How can one fix natbib package error when trying to use or build aiaa paper format template?

I tried to utilize the AIAA template/MWE courtesy CTAN.org. However, when I try building the LaTeX file with natbib, it returns the following error:


Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citation \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers{}
\NAT@force@numbers

Followed by an additional error message:

The 'cite' package should not be used with natbib. Use option 'sort' instead


Meanwhile, if I comment out the line \usepackage{natbib}, and try to re-run LaTeX, it typesets and displays the output file (PDF) although, not without some issues.

For example, the citation number is displayed as a superscript (e.g. ^1) rather than a number within square brackets (e.g. [1]). I tried to tweak the footnotesize line located within the class source code aiaa-tc but that did not seem to work.

I also tried to use PDFLaTeX, XeLaTex and LuaLaTeX to build the file, but these did not work as well.

Here is an MWE:


\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}% insert '[draft]' option to show overfull boxes

% \usepackage{natbib}

 \title{Bare-Bones \LaTeX\ Template for\\
        AIAA Technical Conference Papers}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

Author cited here \cite{xyz90}

% ------------------------------------------------------- %

\clearpage
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}
\bibliography{bibtex_database}


\end{document}


The folder aiaa containing the class source file, may be accessed from the template package which is available for download on CTAN.org in the link above (i.e. https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aiaa?lang=en).

I also tried taking a look at previous threads, but the issue remained unresolved (See links below):

Trying to use natbib, but I get an error that biblatex package is missing
Error in setting up referencing with Natbib plain style: \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations (again!)


Please can someone offer insights as to how to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.



why do you try to use a class that has been updated the last time in 2004?

Please, I would be glad if you could tell me how you know when it was last updated so that I could check for this next time. Also, any suggestions on how I should resolve this issue? Thank you sir

I'm not a sir, I'm a woman. And I simply looked at the dates at the ctan link you provided: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aiaa?lang=en.  And the obvious resolution is not to use such an old class if you don't have to. And if you have to use it, do not try to tweak it.

Okay sorry for the misidentification and thank you for your suggestions. I also tried newer aiaa latex templates including the ones by overleaf but they too have issue when I try to build them on a local computer using texstudio. And I am yet to find another bare bone version. Any suggestions? Thanks

why do you want a aiaa class? Is anyone requiring that from you?

I don't really want an aiaa class per se, rather I want a means to resolve the issue working with natbib. The bibliography seems not to display correctly as I described above.

What happens if you load the natbib package with the option numbers?

look the bibliographystyle \bibliographystyle{aiaa}  is not compatible with natbib. So if you want to use natbib use another class or at least another style.

Alright. I will work on this. Thanks.

@UlrikeFischer - I'm not sure it's been established that natbib itself is incompatible with the aiaa-tc document class and/or the aiaa bibliography style. Rather, it looks like natbib shouldn't be loaded in a way that that makes it try and generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. That's why I asked the OP to see what happens if he/she [!] ran \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}. I suppose one could also give \usepackage[superscript]{natbib} a try.

you do not need to get aiaa-tc from ctan it is part of texlive installed as /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/aiaa/aiaa-tc.cls but only use it if submitting to their journal in which case you should not chaneg the citation or other styles as the journal gets to choose those things not the author

@All Thank you. I use TexStudio. I will check if aiaa-tc ships with it.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks. I have confirmed that the aiaa-tc class package indeed ships with Tex including TexStudio. However, it's bibtex citation and bibliography style (a superscripted numbering system e.g. ^1) is not in the same format as required by the AIAA Journal (which is a square-bracketed numbering system i.e. [1]). Which is somewhat interesting considering that it was apparently created to be a AIAA Journal article template.

The natbib citation management package is fully compatible with the aiaa-tc document class and the aiaa bibliography style as long as you load natbib with the option super, telling natbib to generate superscript-style citation call-outs.

\documentclass{aiaa-tc}

% create a simple bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc:3001,
  author = "Anne Author and Brenda Branson and Carla Christensen",
  year   = 3001,
  title  = "Thoughts",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[super]{natbib} % <-- note the 'super' option
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Piece cited here\cite{abc:3001} \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}


Thanks. I appreciate your contribution. The only thing that is left however, is that aiaa-tc renders citation as a superscript notation as opposed to the AIAA Journal standard that encloses the reference number in square-brackets e.g. [1]

@beebee — As others have already pointed out in their comments, it’s a mystery to us why you insist on using the aiaa-tc document class. If you can choose a different document class, you can switch to using numbers instead of super when loading natbib.

I think I already explained this in the other comment thread as to why I considered using aiaa-tc document class. Except there is another package or class that does similar formatting, I would like to think aiaa-tc is supposed to typeset the document in the AIAA Journal format which is a requirement for submission of articles for publication. Hence, why I brought this issue to the SE community's attention to resolve.
Also, I tried the numbers argument with natbib, and the outcome was the same as before.
Anyways, I should find other alternatives. Thank you.

@beebee - Your claim that changing natbib’s loading option from super to numbers produces the same outcome cannot be correct. To wit, the change modifies the citation call-out style from superscript numerals to baseline numerals encased in square brackets.

Mico -- Clarification: This is what I meant:
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}````
returns superscripted reference notation style.
Of a truth, if I pass the ```article``` as the argument (i.e. ```\documentclass [10pt] {article}``` ) like you suggested, then the reference numbers are enclosed in square brackets. However, this is not without drawbacks. For e.g. the AIAA Journal formatting style (with features such as an Abstract section in bold text, etc.) is now lost while the rest of the document reverts to the default format for articles.

@beebee - I continue to disagree with your claim that \usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib} produces superscript-style citation call-outs if the aiaa-tc document class and the aiaa bibliography style are in use.  The natbib citation management package does not control how the bibliographic entries are formatted; that's the job of the bibliography style -- which you've specified must be aiaa. If you don't like the output that's produced by the aiaa style, then do please settle on some alternative bibliography style.

@beebee - After changing the argument of \bibliographystyle, did you run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

@ Mico: Your reservations are noted. I have tried multiple bibliographic styles including ``\bibliographystyle{aiaa}, `\bibliographystyle{ieee}, \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}```, etc. None of which yielded desired result. Perhaps there's some way to force this style to display... Thanks

@beebee - Let me repeat my preceding comment: Have you run a complete recompile cycle after changing the argument of \bibliographystyle?

@ Mico: Yes, I made sure to typeset (i.e. run Build) the latex file at least twice on each of those instances. I have been getting warnings to avoid extended discussions... As such, I might need to refrain.... Thank you for your contribution, notwithstanding.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ Mico - Hi, please did you get the message I sent in a private chat to you a couple of days ago? Thanks

@beebee - I checked just now and responded to your in-chat query. (I'm currently on vacation with my family and have very little opportunity to hang out on TeX.SE.)

@ Mico: Oh I sincerely apologize for any inconveniences. I hope you have a lovely time on vacation. Thank you for your help!
